# Find and replace text from 2 different files

Tags: notepad++, find, find-and-replace

I have two files and would like to find and replace the strings.

Example:
In file 1

`xyz@gmail.com: asdasda`

In file 2

`asdasda: run_now`

Desired output

`xyz@gmail.com:asdasda: run_now`

OR

`xyz@gmail.com:run_now`

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Pretty sure you would have to find your own solution. [Python Script for Notepad++](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) would be one way  to (possibly) do it.

Comment: You can't do that with Notepad++, you have to write a script in your favorite scripting language. A perl one-liner can easily do such job.